# laravel setup different route according to domain/subdomain

Tags: php, apache, laravel

good day,

I am using Laravel to build both website and APIs for mobile backend, my API controller is setup like this:

```
Route::controller("api/", "ApiController"); //mobile APIs, response is in JSON
```

and other routes and like this:

```
Route::controller("/", "MainController");
```

I need to setup a subdomain for the APIs, for instance:

> http://api.mysite.com

to route directly to API controller, I need that because I don't want the URL to get long and ugly. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'api.mysite.com'), 'ApiController');
```

Comment: thank you so much, and that was quick :)
just small notice, I did use that just had to pass a closure to the function route group. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use route grouping for this. Just point the subdomain to the same location as the normal domain and add a route group.

More information is available in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing).